# Schedule time and date to run script

Tags: python, date, time, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to find a package that can do the following in Python:

- Add/Remove a specified date and time
- Add/Remove it to a scheduler

What I've looked at:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

  - Looks like it only does time, not dates.
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab

  - Does reoccurring days but not a specific date.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a Python scheduler vs something provided natively? crontab doesn't support specific dates so you'll need to use another utility or script to go with it, but on Windows the Task Scheduler will let you schedule scripts to be run on specific dates and times as well as set up recurrence

Comment: The host is going to be a linux box that will attempt to run scripts on a specified date and time so windows wouldn't be an option.  I'm trying to use a python module but i'm really open to suggestions in achieving the above also.

Answer (score 4):

You can use sched to do that.

```
sched.add_job(job_func, trigger='interval', hours=3, start_date='2015-10-10 09:30', end_date='2015-11-10 09:30')
```

You can pass [arguments](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) for trigger. This would set it up to run for 3 hours each day from 2015-10-10 09:30 to until 2015-10-10 09:30. [Interval trigger](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.interval) to set up dates. You can also interchange hours with weeks, hours, days, etc. Hope this helps!

Here's some examples using apscheduler.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=60)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every minute.')

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=17)
def scheduled_job():
    print('This job is run every weekday at 5pm.')

sched.start()
```

Comment: thanks for sharing that snippet.  I'm fairly new to python.  Is there a possibility to show a working example of how to use this? I'm still trying to understand how to read their documentation.  thanks for your help.

Comment: If you get the apscheduler module, you can do alot more. Here's some small code using it. I edited some code into it.

Comment: You should probably mention that `apscheduler` is not in stdlib and therefore something like `pip install apscheduler` or `sudo apt-get install python-apscheduler` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks J.F! Completely forgot to mention that.