# python - working with sched

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I'm fairly new to python.  I was trying to google and find code examples of using sched.

What I would I would like to do:

- Input a date 2015-07-02 and time 23:00:00
- allow a command to run at that specified date and time
- View all the scheduled event
- delete a scheduled event

I'm assuming sched is what I should use.

I've been trying to understand the documentation for sched and was unable to see any clear examples.  Any code examples, a place to learn by examples or better documentation that helps clearly understand sched would be greatly appreciated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python for some ideas

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Schedule time and date to run script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189783/python-schedule-time-and-date-to-run-script)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like with sched that you will need to have some familiarity with the time module as well.   [This chapter of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter15/) is a good introduction to time & datetime and gives a brief example of how to schedule tasks (note this book uses Python 3).  Hope this helps!